# Write $y=-2\sin (x- \frac{\pi}{3})$ in the form $y= a\sin k(x-\beta)$, where a and k are nonnegative

Tags: trigonometry

I would like some help with this question please:

> Write  the following in the form $y= a\sin k(x-\beta)$, where a and k are nonnegative
>   $$y=-2\sin (x- \frac{\pi}{3})$$

I am confused over the effect the negative sign in front of the 2 will have on the expression in brackets. I know that $-\sin x = \sin (-x)$, so does$-2\sin x = 2 \sin (-x)$?

Following on from this, does:
$$y=-2\sin (x- \frac{\pi}{3}) = 2\sin (-x - \frac{\pi}{3})?$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y=-2\sin\left(x-\frac\pi3\right)=2\sin\left(\pi+x-\frac\pi3\right)=\cdots$$  as $\sin(\pi+x)=-\sin x $

Comment: @labbhattacharjee so the answer is $2 \sin (x + \frac{2\pi}{3})$? Also can I check that $y= -2 \sin x = 2 \sin (x + \pi)?$

Comment: @mikoyan, yes. For the Second question, you can use $\sin(A+B)$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee thank you for your help . The hint was useful